# In PHP, how to print a number with 2 decimals, but only if there are decimals already?

Tags: php, javascript, decimal

I have a basic index.php page with some variables that I want to print in several places - here are the variables:

```
<?php
  $firstprice = 1.50;
  $secondprice = 3.50;
  $thirdprice = 20;
?>
```

My challenge is that later in the document, when I print, I get the prices without the second '0' in the price - this is what happens:

```
<?php print "$firstprice";?> // returns 1.5 - not 1.50!
```

SO - I know how to do this with JS, but how is this done in PHP 5+?  Basically I want to print the second '0' if there is already a decimal, so if the variable is equal to '3', it stays as '3', but if it's equal to '3.5' it converts to display '3.50' with a second '0', etc.

Here's a JS example - what's the PHP equivalent?

JS:

```
.toFixed(2).replace(/[.,]00$/, ""))
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: Jon's answer (below) worked really well - thank you Jon!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is simple and it will also let you tweak the format to taste:

```
$var = sprintf($var == intval($var) ? "%d" : "%.2f", $var);
```

It will format the variable as an integer (`%d`) if it has no decimals, and with exactly two decimal digits (`%.2f`) if it has a decimal part.

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/4IONh).

**Update:** As Archimedix points out, this will result in displaying `3.00` if the input value is in the range `(2.995, 3.005)`. Here's an improved check that fixes this:

```
$var = sprintf(round($var, 2) == intval($var) ? "%d" : "%.2f", $var);
```

Comment: This would not account for `.00` obtained through rounding, so I would recommend replacing `.00` in the final result instead of checking the value, or to check the fraction (`$var - floor($var)`) against your rounding threshold, e.g. against `.005` if `$var` is positive, and `0.995` if it is negative.

Comment: Case in point: Assume you calculate prices with tax added, you can get values with a fraction < 0.01 (unless you cut off the resulting value before output).

Comment: @Archimedix: Good catch. I fixed that in the shortest possible manner, to keep the solution an one-liner.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands seperator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

more info here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Not quite... this will also print 2 decimals if the number is an integer, or if the first two decimals round to 0. One would still have to eliminate `.00` afterwards, e.g. using `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
   if (is_float($var)) 
   {
     echo number_format($var,2,'.','');
   }
   else
   {
     echo $var;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this :

```
$value = 15.2; // The value you want to print

$has_decimal = $value != intval($value);
if ($has_decimal) {
    echo number_format($value, 2);
}
else {
    echo $value;
}
```

Notes :

- You can use [**`number_format()`**](https://www.php.net/number_format) to format value to two decimals
- And if the value is an integer, just display it.

Comment: Is it not easy to use `is_float` instead?

Comment: @Shakti : it probably is easier than what I first posted, yes *(and that what I later edited, too ^^ )* ; thanks :-)

Comment: @Shakti Singh In this case yes, but it depends on where he gets the data from.

Comment: @basmegakapa - good point - but in this case the variables are declared in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)():

```
echo number_format($firstprice, 2, ',', '.');
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I changed this slightly to make sure the number formats with a "." instead of a "," to mark the decimal point - it's a difference between the US and EU system for marking numbers - so the result is echo number_format($firstprice, 2, '.', ',');  BUT - this still turns $20 into $20.00 - I want to make sure that numbers with no decimal stay that way ... so what's missing here?

Comment: Oh I see. For this number_format is not the right coice because it appends ,00 EVERYTIME...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively way to print

```
$number = sprintf('%0.2f', $numbers); 
   // 520.89898989 -> 520.89
```