# convert number from 12 to 12.00

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, how to print a number with 2 decimals, but only if there are decimals already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648205/in-php-how-to-print-a-number-with-2-decimals-but-only-if-there-are-decimals-al)

Brothers I want to convert me any way I entered into a text field automatically turns
12 to 12.00

How possible work by php and javascript

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, how to print a number with 2 decimals, but only if there are decimals already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648205/in-php-how-to-print-a-number-with-2-decimals-but-only-if-there-are-decimals-al) and/or [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP its easy to do that by doing:

```
number_format($numberVar, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [number_format() from PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format(12, 2)
```

Comment: hey, you got a -1 to, someone's a grump

Comment: you answered the question correctly, seemed valid, plus fair

Answer (score 1):

What, no javascript?

```
var x = 3;
alert(x.toFixed(2)); // 3.00
```

Will "work" for the case given, but so will:

```
alert(x + '.00');
```

There are [bugs](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-rndg1.htm#toF) in [`toFixed`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5) in some older browsers with certain values so many write their own simple routine.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention JS.

Answer (score -2):

```
$thisnum = $thisnum . ".00";
```

Proof of concept:

```
$thisnum = $thisnum . ".00";
echo ($thisnum + 4.55);
```

However, as pointed out by the community, this is something that will only work for the case mentioned in the question and will not handle any use cases that already have decimals. The other answers are better.

Comment: Good concept, but what if `$thisnum` is 12.00 or 12.00256?

Comment: Then it isn't turning 12 into 12.00, which is what the question asked. I'll admit the other answers (which I didn't see until after I had posted) were better than mine, but I don't see getting -2 for answering the question that was asked.

Comment: True, but this answer assumes only a specific case. When possible, don't reinvent the wheel, but also give answers which can apply to a variety of cases, not just the example that was used in this question. I retract my -1.

Comment: Actually, unless you edit your answer, I can't retract my -1.

Comment: Understood, my apologies, I do believe I should leave the answering to people much smarter than I.